# How to reference a Button without creating a variable for it in the controller

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have an FXML file in which I have a lot of buttons. The Buttons have id's of the format "button1" to "button149".

The normal way to change the text of buttons on runtime when an onAction event is triggered, would be the following code:

```
public class GUIController{
  public Button button1;
  public Button button2;
  .
  .
  .
  public Button button149;
  
  public void handleButtonClick(){
    button1.setText("test");
    button2.setText("test");
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

This has the obvious problem that I would need to have 150 lines of code to define all the button variables.

So I am wondering:

Is there a way to change the properties like text or color of a button without creating a variable for it in the controller, but directly referring to it using its ID?

Or is there a way to somehow create a list or an array of all the buttons so I can have a variable for each one without writing a line of code for each button?

EDIT:
It should be mentioned that all the buttons are in a gridPane. One per field. Maybe that provides options to solve this problem.

Comment: java naming conventions ..

Comment: Declaring 150 `Button` elements in the FXML file is questionable. Could you not create the buttons in the controller using a loop? That way you can store the buttons in a list or map or something.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution. I will try doing that.

Answer (score 1):

---

The best way to optimize your code is to have a table of those buttons like you said. But you cannot work without declaring a button on which you will make changes.

In the other hand, it is possible to declare, in the controller, only the action handler method of a given button without defining the button. You just need to make sure that the method is mentionned on the XML or Scene Builder side.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give a suggestion on how such a table (I guess in form of a List) would be generated?

Comment: On the top of your controller, create list of Nodes or Button like this `Button buttons[] = new Button[149]` . You can easily put your 150 buttons in a such table and access them by their index.

Comment: try to regroup them all in an anchorpane for example and loop on it like this `for (Node node : pane.getChildren()) {
        if (node instanceof Button) {
             buttons[i] = (Button) node;
        }
}`